# How to calculate the average created_at between range?

Tags: laravel

I have an attendance program that must display the average time in range of days on `created_at` column. Currently, I've done this by doing so:

```php
/**
 * Show the average arrival time from user's attendance
 * records between today and last month.
 *
 * @author Donny Pratama <donnypratama1024@gmail.com>
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function showAverageAttendanceTime()
{
    $today = Carbon::now();
    $lastMonth = Carbon::now()->subDays(30);

    $averageArrivalTime = auth()->user()->attendances()
        ->select('created_at')
        ->whereBetween('created_at', [$lastMonth, $today])
        ->avg('created_at');

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'data' => [
            'average_arrival_time' => Carbon::parse($averageArrivalTime)->toTimeString()
        ]
    ]);
}
```

The problem is, at some cases, Carbon cannot parse the string and threw this error:

> Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (20200311271139.3796) at position 12 (3): Unexpected character in file /Users/stechoq/Documents/Programs/Laravel/prismahr-backend/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Traits/Creator.php on line 81

Could somebody please help me?

**EDIT**

I'm trying to avoid using raw SQL queries if possible.

Comment: What does `dd($averageArrivalTime);` tell you?

Comment: It shows me this string `"20200311271139.3796"`

Comment: Hmm, probably because `avg` doesn't know to treat date like a date.

Comment: yea, i think so.. I've been surfing the internet for a while but can't get any information about ranged time calculation. There is a bunch but only accepts 2 parameters and in this case, I need all of them to be calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought, you could try something like this:

```
$averageArrivalTime = auth()->user()->attendances()
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$lastMonth, $today])
    ->avg(DB::raw('FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at)'));

Carbon::createFromTimestamp($averageArrivalTime)->toTimeString();
```

Treat the date like a number to get an accurate average, and then convert it back.

Comment: ah beautiful.. and it works. thank you very much.. :D

Comment: Hi @miken32 .. I just realized that using the above method is not calculating the average time. Instead, it being renewed by the current time. I mean, at the beginning of implementation, it's shows 2 AM (my local time). Now it's 5 AM :/

Comment: Can you help me one more time please? I really have no idea about this :/

Comment: I’m not sure. Maybe post a new question with sample inputs and expected output.